# How to set up VSCode Flutter project to correctly resolve Java code in the Android folder?

Tags: java, android, dart, visual-studio-code, flutter

VSCode as of version 1.30.1 with Flutter extension v2.22.1 doesn't set up the Java classpaths for the android folder so working with `MainActivity` is a pain, and I'm kind of afraid to touch things because as soon as I start I break Flutter's build systems and then things break there. Does anyone know how to set up VSCode to work as expected with both Flutter & Android code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Flutter extension for VS Code only supports editing Dart code for Flutter, it does not add any support for Java.

There's some discussion about this here:

https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/25369

It may be possible to get working, but since it's not an official supported setup I'm unsure how easy or how well it'd work.

FWIW, if you right-click on the `android` folder in VS Code, there should be an option to `Open in Android Studio` which might at least make it quicker to jump into modifying there :-)